# How to add navigation buttons in outlook add-on?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Is there any way to add back button, more options button like (log out, help, manage) to our outlook add-ons.I googled it, but end up with no answers relevant to that. Currently, I'm doing it by placing images of back button below the plugin title panel.

I expect this to be on the title panel so that it looks better.is there any ways to do that?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit, your query is not clear to me. Are you using add-in for Mobile(Android/iOS), Online or Desktop client?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Add-in for web Application

Answer (score 0):

Using [command bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/navigation-patterns#command-bar), [tab bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/navigation-patterns#tab-bar) and [back button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/navigation-patterns#back-button) are the recommended UX design pattern for navigation in Office add-ins.

Comment: Yes, I have gone through this. but I couldn't find any docs on how to apply this in my design.

Comment: You can use [Fluent UI](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/commandbar) or [Fabric JS](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric-js/components/commandbar/commandbar)